# CGPoint inside CGImageRef

Tags: ios, cgpoint, cgimageref

Can I know if a `CGPoint` is inside a `CGImageRef`?
Or I should convert `CGImageRef` in other format?

**UPDATE**

```
maskcontext = CGBitmapContextCreate(currentM, w, 
                                               h,
                                               bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                               kCGImageAlphaNone);
maskImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(maskcontext);
```

where `currentM` is an `unsigned char`, `maskcontext` is a `CGContextRef`
and `maskImage` is a `CGImageRef` and I want to know its `rect`.

Comment: I have a cgimageref where I color this image; and I want to know when i touch the device; if the touch is inside this cgimageref or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you get the frame of your image? Then you could do:

```
CGRectContainsPoint ( CGRect rect, CGPoint point )
```

To see if that point is inside that frame.

Comment: Your image has to be inside of some view or something, take it from there

Comment: I don't know how to do it...can you help me?

Comment: Yes, tell me how do you draw the image and I will tell you how to get the frame

Comment: w and h are the withd and the hegith of your image, so you can create a CGRect frame with that and the X and Y of the origing, do you know what are they?